# Detect if png has (and actually uses) an alpha channel in node

Tags: node.js, image-processing, png, minify, alpha

Is there anyway to detect if a .png file has (and is actually using) an alpha channel in node.js?

I'm writing a service to minify image file sizes, and [imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin)/[optipng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optipng) don't appear to strip out unnecessary alpha channels, so I'd like to do so manually to further minify (probably with [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs)).

Comment: pngcrush (discalimer: I wrote it) will remove an unused alpha channel if you use the "-reduce" option.  So will imagemagick's "convert" program.

Comment: If you need to detect a png alpha channel for whatever other reason, you can inspect `buffer[25] === 6`. [Source](https://github.com/tj/node-png-has-alpha/blob/master/index.js#L24)

Comment: buffer[25]==6 means the color type is RGBA, so an alpha channel is present but it might be all-opaque.  buffer[25] can also be 4 in the case of gray-alpha pixels, or 3 in the case of indexed-color which can have an alpha channel carried separately in the tRNS chunk.  Unfortunately the only way of telling whether alpha is actually used is to examine the pixels.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Ah, good to know. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: In fact, PNG color-types 0 and 2 (Gray or RGB) can also have GIF-style transparency in which the tRNS chunk names a color that is transparent.  For your purpose, though, there's no impact on filesize other than the space (less than 20 bytes) occupied by the tRNS chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Apparently imagemin/optipng do remove unnecessary alpha channels... I don't know why my initial tests showed otherwise. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save on file size then since .png is lossless format it will actually be better if you will convert the images with no transparency to .jpeg instead of removing the alpha channel.

It could cut your image size by half.